# Use node.js only for one of its modules to perform operations on a mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nlp

I'd very much like to use the `natural` module (which seems to do fine nlp in javascript, which is rare) to perform operations in one of my mongodb scripts, but I don't care about any network stuff, server stuff or anything else. **And** I've never used node.js.

So I have several questions:

- can I use the `natural` module without loading the whole node.js environment? If I can, how?
- If I can't, how can I create the minimal node.js application, that won't mess with mongo to just get the advantages of `natural` without getting into troubles?

If you've other pointers to sharpen my understanding of node.js for this matter I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could extract enough of the source code of the `natural` node.js package and its dependencies into your mongo script to make it work w/o node, but that would be painful.  node.js isn't an environment like you're thinking; it's just a program that installs like any other program and has no effect on your system until you use it to run a script file, and then it only does what you've told it to in your script file.  If that script file just does work with the `natural` module, it will have no effect on mongo or networking.